# Error when setting workbook variable - 2147352565

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a simple code that runs upon initialization of a userform that sets a few workbook and worksheet variables so they can be used easily throughout the rest of my modules, and the references can be easily changed in one place if the file moves.  I recently migrated my workbooks from my desktop to a separate server/drive, and accordingly updated the file pathways; however, when I try to run the code now I immediately get the message:

"Run-time error '-2147352565 (8002000b)': Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."

This error occurs on the line

```
Set ReportWkbk = Workbooks("N:\ rest of file pathway here\QuaRT_Template.xlsm")
```

Is there anything that can be happening on the server/drive that is causing this issue?  If so, is there anything I can do to fix it?  I do work with other excel workbooks saved in the same location that seem to have no issue being referenced, though their references are in the workbook itself, not through Visual Basic.

Comment: It would help to show more of your code, including the declarations for your variables.

Comment: Sorry, it's correct in the code.  I copied it over wrong.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's fixed now to correctly represent what I have in Visual Basic.

Comment: There's not really enough code there to offer any useful suggestions.  Is the workbook being referenced open in Excel?

Comment: Are you using any ActiveX controls on the Form that aren't in the common controls?

Comment: @TimWilliams  I know, that's how far it makes it into my code before the error.  Yes, the workbook is open.  The main issue is that the code works properly, I've used it for quite awhile, but it can no longer assign this workbook.  The only change is the file pathway, since I have now migrated this file to a shared drive.

Comment: If the path is correct then that should work.  Try - `Dim w:For Each w in Workbooks: Debug.Print w.FullName:Next w` and compare the output to the path in your code.

Comment: @Comintern Nope.  I saw that issue on another question, but unfortunately that's not what's happening.  The line of code shown above is the very first thing that happens in my code, so it appears to be directly related to finding this workbook.  I've tripled checked the file pathway, and everything is correct.

Comment: @TimWilliams I just entered in your code, but unfortunately I do have the correct file pathway according to your method as well

Comment: Try just `Workbooks("QuaRT_Template.xlsm")`

Comment: I did just run the code again, and this time it came up with "Run-time error '9: Subscript out of range".  Nothing has changed, so I'm not sure why the change in error message.

Comment: @TimWilliams Works great, thanks! So simple.  I do later reference another file in the same drive, so hopefully the same issue doesn't pop up again.  Any idea what was causing the issue, or probably just a glitch?

Comment: @A.Dough - That usually means the workbook isn't open.

Answer (score 0):

The `Subscript Out of Range` error occurs because the Excel workbook being referenced is not open (or opening) in **the same** instance of Excel. You can easily reproduce the error by creating two workbooks (name one WorkBook2.xlsx) and ensuring they open in separate instances of Excel. Then run this code:

```
Sub OpenWkbkNames()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    For Each wbk In Workbooks
        Debug.Print wbk.Name
    Next
    'Hmm. Workbook 2 is not listed, but lets activate it and see what happens.
    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

You could avoid the issue by looping through the names of the workbooks open in *THIS* instance of Excel to ensure its available.

I've been researching `Run-time error '-2147352565 (8002000b)'` and found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.disp_e_badindex.aspx

Apparently, that is VS's way of saying `Subscript Out of Range` too. I suspect (but have no solid proof) that since the code worked locally but the issue appeared after the file was migrated to a shared drive that Windows is taking a long time to open the file so opens it in a new instance of Excel. Essentially, Excel gets impatient and decides to move on while Windows completes its task. I base this assumption on the detection logic that was added to Excel 2013 (https://blogs.office.com/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/).

Comment: Thanks! This is great!