# Excel VBA run time error when working with multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub ImportSolarData()

Dim Year As Integer
Dim DataBookName As Variant

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceBook As Workbook
Dim SourceSheetName As String

Dim TargetBook As Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheetName As String

DataBookName = Application.GetOpenFilename

If DataBookName = False Then
    MsgBox ("You pressed cancel")
    GoTo LeaveNow
End If

MsgBox (DataBookName)

Year = InputBox("Enter the Year you wish to Import")
SourceSheetName = Str(Year)

Workbooks.Open Filename:=DataBookName
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name, , "Active Workbook Name"
MsgBox SourceSheetName, , "Source Sheet Name"

Sheets(SourceSheetName).Select

LeaveNow:

End Sub
```

The code falls over at the last line - with the error

> Run-time error '-2147352565 (8002000b)': The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.

But I don't have a single chart in the frame - anywhere.  I don't have one, haven't tried to create one, and the active workbook doesn't have any charts at all.

Anyone any ideas please - this is ruining my weekend! (Running Excel 365 on OSX Sierra)

Comment: I'm just an amateur, and have no idea of your problem. But may be [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38572824/1726522) can be related to your problem.

Comment: There are plenty of errors and unnecessary steps but it will be difficult to help if you don't tell us what the code *should be doing*. Also - it seems as though you're using msgbox to check your code. Can this be removed in the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last few lines of code with the ones below.  Your input box for some reason puts a leading blank space before the 4 digit year. In essence it was searching for a sheet named " 2015" when the name of the sheet is actually "2015" - without a leading space.  The trim() function corrects that. Secondly, you didn't set the workbook or reference it in your final select command.

Other than that it looks like good coding.

```
Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(DataBookName, True, True)
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name, , "Active Workbook Name"
MsgBox SourceSheetName, , "Source Sheet Name"

SourceBook.Worksheets(Trim(SourceSheetName)).Select
```

Comment: Thanks - this was my first ever post to a forum - never actually expected an answer - let alone a solution.  Many thanks to @JohnRichter for this